# How to know if my page is running in a facebook iframe or not

Tags: php, facebook

I'm currently developing a site which runs standalone and as a facebook app on an iframe
I was wondering what whold be "best practice" for checking if my page is ran in a facebook iframe before the page loads so I can preset the relevant CSS and other variables

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this. If you're not concerned about security (i.e. you really only want to know how to format the page rather than deciding what content to show) then your best bet may be to use a distinct url for Facebook access. For example if your standalone site is www.mysite.com you can configure fb.mysite.com or www.mysite.com/fb to point to the same place, then use the alternate version in your app settings. Your server code can then easily check which url version is being accessed and act accordingly. Of course you have to take some care with your links to make sure they maintain the correct prefix.

Another way is to use signed_request as discussed, setting a cookie (or session) when it is present to indicate a Facebook access. The trick there is to also include a bit of javascript code at the top of each page that checks to make sure the page is within an iframe. If not, then the code immediately redirects back to the current page with a parameter added like "?clearfb=1" which will tell the server to clear the cookie/session and output the page in external format.

Comment: I take it that the "bit of javascript code" you refer to  is window.top==window?

Comment: Yes, something along the lines of `if (window.location==top.location) window.location='thispage.php?clearfb=1';` at the top of each page, but *only* if the server is currently outputting in iframe format. And of course the appropriate server-side code to detect the clearfb parameter and react appropriately.

Comment: @FloydWilburn, BTW accessing `top.location` if `window != window.top` will rise security warning if domains differ due to cross domain policy.

Comment: If you use distinct URLs setup as detailed above, you could also use mod_rewrite to route all requests through the same actual page.

Answer (score 6):

```
$signed_request = $_POST['signed_request'];

if(empty($signed_request))
      die('No direct access.');
```

Answer (score 3):

checking to see if a [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) is present would also be a good test...

Comment: Checking signed_request is the best way to know that the page is inside the Facebook framework (as opposed to merely being inside an iframe somewhere) but remember that it is only set on the first load. You'll have to have some way to "persist" the setting as the user follows links to new pages.

Comment: why `only set on first load`? I can not find any reference to this behavior.
Can you please link us to this information?

Comment: I don't know that it is explicitly stated anywhere, it's just the way that the iframe setup works. When the page framework is constructed, the iframe is populated by sending a POST to the canvas url with signed_request as a parameter. That's the only time signed_request will be automatically sent. After that Facebook has no way to send it again, since the iframe is then under control of the app. The only way to get signed_request sent again is to reload the entire page (using top.location or similar) which is in fact what some people do, but it's definitely not recommended.

Comment: Yes, `top.location` defiantly would set you up with another `signed_request`, and yes again - many people do it; **NOT RECOMMENDED**.
Its possible to place the signed request in a session variable or store it in a JS variable.  My practice is to parse it as soon as it is there and weave it into the pages server-side logic and at all times avoid pointlessly reloading the entire page again.

Comment: Thanks guys, but it still doesn't cover what I need, since if I save the data in the browser session then after I open the same page outside the facebook iframe it still uses the same session.           there must be a way to know this... @FloydWilburn

Comment: See the separate answer I have just added for a way to handle that situation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some php code to test if the current page is running inside a facebook iframe :

```
if( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ], "apps.facebook.com" ) !== false ){
    // Page is running in Facebook iframe
}
```

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is sent by the browser and should not be trusted to be accurate or there at all.

Comment: this is very true - evil users ;)

Comment: This is the best and concise approach for me that want only to add one line of CSS.

Comment: @gio - If that's *really* all you want to do then I totally agree with you.

Comment: @gio - check out my edit, it would be wise to include it. The return value of the `strpos()` function [comes with a warning](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues)

Comment: @Lix - Yes, although the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` returns "https://apps.facebook.com/[appname]/", so it was right anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The only real check for this can be done on client-side by comparing `window.top==window` if it's true Application is run outside of an `iframe`.

There is no server side check that can ensure this since browsers not passing information about parent frames to server other than HTTP_REFERRER which cannot be trusted.

Facebook passing signed_request to your application if running on *Canvas* of *Page Tab Canvas* but this isn't something you can fully trust since it can be mimicked by user too.

**Update**:

The statement that this is the only real check doesn't mean you should use it! You better stick to `signed_request` based solution, since it's a way Facebook interact with your apps, users are not intended to use signed_request and it **should not under any conditions** be passed as Part of query string! If user mimicking it, something is probably wrong, I wouln't bother providing wrong styling in that case.

Comment: if the only reason for doing this check is different CSS files, you can load 'em on client side by injecting correct `link` tags before page fully loaded since check for `window.top==window` will work at any time event before DOM is loaded.

Comment: Actually signed_request is the *only* method that can be fully trusted. I don't think the original question is really about security because it specifically mentions CSS changes, but it's wrong to say that signed_request is in the same category as HTTP_REFERER or javascript window tests.

Comment: @Floyd Wilburn, it can be trusted for user identity not to ensure app is running in `iframe`. Sure it's different category, it's verified by authority you trust - Facebook. Updated my answer to clarify

Comment: Well yes, but that part was always assumed because checking if a page is inside *any* iframe is pointless, and we were clearly talking about being inside the *Facebook* iframe. Why would anybody manually send a signed_request parameter to a page outside an iframe? If they wanted to "hack" something, they could just as easily put it inside an iframe, so I see no reason to even consider the case where signed_request is present but the page is not inside an iframe.

Comment: Consider form with target attribute other than self, containing current signed_request as one of fields - this technique may be very helpful in some cases (I used it for a couple of apps too)

Comment: But again, that has nothing to do with the original question or the scenarios being discussed. Of course you (as the app/website programmer) can structure something like that. When talking about security and trust, it's clear that the concern is about a *user* being able to take advantage in some way. And as I said, there is simply no advantage (from a hacking perspective) to taking the parameters that are being sent to a Facebook iframe, and instead sending them to the same page outside the iframe. Therefore it is perfectly valid to assume that [signed_request]=[page in Facebook iframe].

Comment: checking signed_request didn't work in my case because it is set in either case (inside an iFrame or just calling the page from the server). Probably has to do something with the fact that I am instantiating a facebook object that is used throughout the app, so in this case I HAD to go for the window.top==window solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same question this morning - I want desktop users to access my app through facebook but I want mobile users to be able to access the app directly via URL.  Like Floyd Wilburn said, accessing the different versions of the app through different URLs is a good option, but instead of having two copies of the app (hard to maintain) I used mod_rewrite to rewrite the /facebook directory to the app root:

```
# rewrite both /facebook and / to same place so you
# can tell if your request came from facebook or from direct URL access :)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /facebook*
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L]
```

Be sure to set your Facebook page tab URL to land in the /facebook subdirectory.  Now, you can browser sniff to see if they're a mobile or desktop user, and you can test the requested URL to see if they're accessing the app through Facebook or directly :)

Let me add that there is NO foolproof way to determine either the client type or access point - both can be spoofed by someone who knows what they're doing - so take this into consideration when designing your app's security and authentication mechanisms.